# how to sort data based on nested entity property in jpa @query method

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to get sorted posts according to publish Date

```
public class UserProfile {
    
    @Id
    private Long profileId;

    @ManyToMany(cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST},mappedBy="postedOnUserProfiles")
    private List<Post> posts=new ArrayList<Post>();
    
}
    
public class Post {
    
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="gen4",strategy="sequence")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="gen4")
    
    
    @ManyToMany
    //@JoinColumn(name="profileId")
    @JoinTable(
              name = "postedOnUserProfiles", 
              joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "postId"), 
              inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "profileId"))
    private List<UserProfile> postedOnUserProfiles=new ArrayList<UserProfile>(); 

    private int shareCount=0;
    private int commentCount=0;
    
    private int likeCount=0;
    private int wowCount=0;
    private int heartCount=0;
    private int weepEyesCount=0;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Comment> postComments=new ArrayList<Comment>();
    
    private Date publishDate=new Date();
}

@Repository
public interface UserProfileRepo extends JpaRepository<UserProfile, Long>{

    @Query(" SELECT posts  From UserProfile up  where up.profileId=:userProfileId order by up.posts.publishDate")
    public Page<Post> findPostByOfProfilePageable(long userProfileId,Pageable pageable);
}
```

I want to get posts according to post.publishDate.
Please give me any solution

Answer (score 3):

1. You are selecting posts, not userProfiles, so the method should be in PostRepository
2. Since your method already consumes Pageable, you could provide sorting rule in it

```
@Query(" SELECT p From Post p where p.authorId=:userProfileId")
public Page<Post> findPostByOfProfilePageable(long userProfileId,Pageable pageable);
```

Client:

```
postRepo.findPostByOfProfilePageable(prodileId, PageRequest.of(0, 20, Sort.by("punlishDate”));
```

Answer (score 1):

use `java.util.Collections.sort()` and implement the comparable interface for your Post class.

see example here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-comparator-comparable